# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable | Jupyter Notebook |

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
    print ('hello world')
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 print ('hello world')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Why is this coming????

Comment: Seems like `print` is a string for some reason

Comment: Can you check in your code if there's any statement that starts with `print = ` ?

Comment: Even if you deleted cell in notebook where you have assigned the variable this variable is still stored in memory, Restart Kernel in jupyter in this case.

Comment: Or simply run `del print` to remove the offending variable.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem when I start using Jupyter Notebook
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp6Yz.png)

but, I closed all of it, not just The file that I was running, all Jupyter notebook
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU1Xy.png)

and than it worked for me with no proplems at all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiDxO.png)